Merging duplicated rows and create new column based on which rows were duplicated
Let's say I have the following:
df=read.table(text="ID ColB ColC ColD
1 A S1 X,Y,Z
2 A S2 A,B,C
3 B S3 A,B,C
4 B S4 X
5 C S6 X
6 C S8 X
", header=TRUE)

I want to merge duplicated rows based on ColB while merging ColC and ColD on these rows, such as the results are:
df <- read.table(text="ID ColB ColC ColD
1 A S1,S2 X,Y,Z,A,B,C
2 B S3,S4 A,B,C,X
3 C S6,S8 X
", header=TRUE)

As you can see, because ColD, row 5 a 6 had the same value, the resulting ColD row 3 contains only the X value.

library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(ColD = toString(unique(ColD)), 
         ColC = toString(ColC),
         .by = ColB) %>% 
  slice_head(by=ColB)

  ID ColB   ColC         ColD
1  1    A S1, S2 X,Y,Z, A,B,C
2  3    B S3, S4     A,B,C, X
3  5    C S6, S8            X


Using aggregate and strsplit, unlist and coerce toString, finally add a new ID column.
> aggregate(cbind(ColC, ColD) ~ ColB, df, \(x) {
+   unique(unlist(strsplit(x, ','))) |> toString()
+ }) |> 
+   transform(id=seq_along(ColB))
  ColB   ColC             ColD id
1    A S1, S2 X, Y, Z, A, B, C  1
2    B S3, S4       A, B, C, X  2
3    C S6, S8                X  3

If you don't love spaces you can pipe into paste(collapse=',') instead of toString().
Note, that it would look very similar if the columns "ColC" and "ColD" were objects of class "list",
> df2
  ID ColB ColC    ColD
1  1    A   S1 X, Y, Z
2  2    A   S2 A, B, C
3  3    B   S3 A, B, C
4  4    B   S4       X
5  5    C   S6       X
6  6    C   S8       X  

where
> str(df2, 1)
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  4 variables:
 $ ID  : int  1 2 3 4 5 6
 $ ColB: chr  "A" "A" "B" "B" ...
 $ ColC:List of 6
 $ ColD:List of 6

but we would need a different approach:
> by(df2, df2$ColB, \(x) {
+   data.frame(el(x$ColB), 
+              t(lapply(x[c('ColC', 'ColD')], unlist) |> lapply(unique))) |>
+     setNames(names(x)[-1])
+ }) |> 
+   c('make.row.names'=FALSE) |> 
+   do.call(what='rbind') |> 
+   transform(id=seq_along(ColB))
  ColB   ColC             ColD id
1    A S1, S2 X, Y, Z, A, B, C  1
2    B S3, S4       A, B, C, X  2
3    C S6, S8                X  3


Data:
> dput(df)
structure(list(ID = 1:6, ColB = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"
), ColC = c("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S6", "S8"), ColD = c("X,Y,Z", 
"A,B,C", "A,B,C", "X", "X", "X")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
> dput(df2)
structure(list(ID = 1:6, ColB = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", "C"
), ColC = list("S1", "S2", "S3", "S4", "S6", "S8"), ColD = list(
    c("X", "Y", "Z"), c("A", "B", "C"), c("A", "B", "C"), "X", 
    "X", "X")), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")


Very nice base approach, just note that ColD has duplicated X and it should appear  once.

library("dplyr")

df %>% 
  group_by(ColB) %>%
  group_modify(~{
    tibble(ColC = list(unique(.x$ColC)),
           ColD = list(unique(.x$ColD)) )
  })


Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?
